# How to do global error handling for NextJS api?

Tags: typescript, next.js, monitoring, observability

For getting the stack trace of the error and push it to external system such as NewRelic etc. is there a way to configure Global error handler which wraps all the APIs
So that making changes to all the APIs (multiple files is not required, DRY principle).

Comment: Do you mean error logging for Next JS `/api` serverless functions or the frontend ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I mean for /api  , APIs developed in NextJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a resusable `withErrorHandler` high order function to wrap your `/api` handlers like so :-

```js
import logger from 'some-logger';

const withErrorHandler = (handler) => async (req, res) => {
  try {
    return handler(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    // logger comes here
    // your return statement based on error
  }
};
```

Suppose your handler looks like :-

```js
const handler = (req,res) => {
// doing something
}
```

You can export it like so :-

```js
export default withErrorHandler(handler)
```

Comment: thanks Lakshya , was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    // super calls the constructor of the parent class
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    //  captureStackTrace returns a string that reperesents the location of that particular error in the call. gives us a stack that helps us to find the location of that error in the code. this will help us to find the exact error in our code.
    // "this" is object itself, "this.constructor" constructor of this class
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

export default ErrorHandler;
```

then in api routes

```
if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found with this ID.", 400));
  }
```

Comment: this would requires changes at multiple places , what I am more interested towards is DRY(Do not repeat yourself)  principle in NextJS framework as mentioned in question.